# Change svg color with vite-plugin-svgr

Tags: reactjs, svg, vite, emotion

I'm using [vite](https://vitejs.dev/) with [emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction) and [vite-plugin-svgr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-svgr). I want to change the color of `MyIcon`. I've tried fill, color etc. but it's not working. What am I supposed to do?

```js
import { ReactComponent as MyIcon } from "../icons/dummy.svg";

function MyComponent() {
  const icon = css({
    fill: "blue", // this is not working
  });

  return <MyIcon css={icon} />;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 64 64" fill="#FF0000">
    <path d="..." style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);"/> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Is your icon included as an inlined `<svg>` (inspect it in dev tools) or as an `<img>` (you can't access fill im images)?

Comment: SVGR uses <svg>. Fill is just a placeholder for a correct solution to the problem.

Comment: So you see a rendered icon but ... black (default fill color) or in another color? Please share your rendered HTML/svg output (copy the lement via dev tools inspection) as a snippet. Keep in mind there's a good chance, your icon svg asset file has some flaws e.g by applying a `fill:none` to the parent svg while having specific fills for `<path>` elements – so you would have some css specificity issues.

Comment: vite-plugin-svgr applies a fill to the path element. I've edited my question with the html part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to change the `fill` of my .svg file to `currentColor`.

If one does not want to edit the .svg file, SVGR gives the option to replace an attribute:
https://react-svgr.com/docs/options/#replace-attribute-value

But be careful that only element attributes can be replaced, not style attributes. So first they need to be converted using `convertStyleToAttrs`:
https://github.com/svg/svgo#built-in-plugins